# Order of the group $G=\langle x,y : x^9=y^3=1, yx=x^4y \rangle$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\langle x,y : x^9=y^3=1, yx=x^4y \rangle$ . Then how to show that $|G|\le 27$ ?

I have no idea on how to proceed to this problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Using the identity $yx = x^4 y$, any word involving the generators $x$ and $y$ can be rewritten in the form $x^m y^n$ for some integers $m, n$. Now use the identities $x^9 = y^3 = 1$ to upper bound the number of distinct elements of that form.

Comment: can you write $yx^5y$ as $x^my^n $ ... ?

Comment: @user521337 $yx^5 y = (yx) x^4 y = x^4 y x^4 y = x^8 y x^3 y = x^{12} y x^2 y = \cdots$

Comment: The upper bound is basically rule of product: $|G|\leq |C_3\times C_9|=3\times 9=27$, with $C_n$ being the cyclic group of order $n$.